# How do you practice for proofs?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

I am in the second semester of my engineering course, and have to take advanced mathematics as a compulsory. I have been absolutely struggling with proofs in general, since pure math has never been my strong suit. People have told me something along the line of, "if you just draw logical conclusions from each and every step, you'll be able to prove (the statement)". Aside from the fact that this statement is too vague, I always feel like there is always a certain way that the proofs should be done, because professors and lecturers do it in a certain manner. But since every person has their own way for proofs, there is just so much grey in this area of mathematics. I just wanna wanna know, what tips and resources you guys would give a person who is struggling with it.

Comment: What kinds of proofs do you want help with? In general I'd say experience helps a lot, but I'm sure you're tired of hearing that as well

Comment: If you are learning real analysis, then the proof problems do require the appropriate knowledge of definition. Now by appropriate knowledge I intend to mean you should be able to realize the situation and understand which definition you need to apply. In almost all the problem you should identify the goal, and start with the ethical definition, and in between that you need some bit of skill. However the most important thing is you need practice and that gives experience.

Comment: Adding to Subham's comment (which I agree, immediately converting the statement to the definition is very helpful) I would say that doing some formal logic and getting used to manipulating quantifiers (like "there exists" and "for all") is something I've found immensely useful in this context

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips. I am currently doing calculus, especially mutivariable calculus and topology.

Comment: Find math problems that involve your proving something, rather than computing an answer.  Then, find a professor to critique your proof for validity.  Alternatively, find a forum, like this one, and submit mathSE questions, 1 at a time, along the lines of "Is this proof valid?"

Comment: *calculus, especially mutivariable calculus and topology* --- Perhaps being more specific would help? When I think of calculus, I think of high school to first year college; for multivariable calculus, first year or second year college; for topology, advanced undergraduate or graduate work. This spans up to 5 years . . . (Probably all you need to do is to say what your textbook is.)